# Package snow: makeCluster hangs

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, snow

I have trouble with the initialization of a cluster with the snow package on R 3.4.2 on a Windows machine.

When I run the following code, R hangs after the last line without ever setting up the cluster:

```
library(snow)
nodes <- rep("localhost",2)

cl <- makeCluster(nodes, type="SOCK")
```

Specifications of versions and OS (taken from sessionInfo()):

- R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
- Snow: snow_0.4-2

It seems that my problem is related to the version of R because everything works (i.e. the cluster is set up and can be used) if I run it on R 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) on the same machine with the same snow-package.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this issue? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As a starter, the 'snow' package is considered "deprecated" and replaced by the 'parallel' package. Try with `parallel::makeCluster()` instead unless you are using legacy code that requires 'snow'.

Comment: Hi @HenrikB , thanks a lot, using the 'parallel' package solves the problem!

Comment: Hi @HenrikB I actually have a follow up question to your answer: You mention that 'snow' is deprecated. However, I still need to install the package snow, otherwise `parallel::makeCluster()` throws the error: 'there is no package called snow'. Bu then, why is 'snow' deprecated if 'parallel' still has a dependency?

Comment: Sorry, all fine. I need to drop the argument 'type' in `makeCluster()`.

Comment: Yes, there are some legacy dependencies in there, but as you noticed only for certain choices of `type`. See `print(parallel::makeCluster)` for which.

Comment: @HenrikB thanks the parallel also worked for me.  Strangely a few times prior it worked well with just makeCluster but stop all of sudden.  I'm using the doSNOW package.